# C# writing JSON to a file without backslashes

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on a console application that writes certain data to a JSON file. The problem is that the backslashes that VS uses to escape characters in a string, are being written to the file. I did find a similar question like this on stackoverflow, but that person was serializing twice which caused the problem. I don't think that's the case with me (unless I'm missing something) and that's why I created a seperate question on here.

I've tried doing string.Replace("\","") but since the backslashes aren't really there ('cause it's just VS escaping the double quotes), this doesn't help.

I have a class called listItem which has some properties;

```
class ListItem
    {
        public string title;
        public string textline;
        public string docuType;
    }
```

and I have a class SPList, containing a list of those ListItems;

```
class SPList
    {
        public string listTitle;
        public List<ListItem> listItems;
    }
```

I have an example of what's being written to the JSON-file with 2 lists;

```
[
  {
    "listTitle": "\"Another List\"",
    "listItems": [
      {
        "title": "\"Here\"",
        "textline": "\"Another test value\"",
        "docuType": null
      },
      {
        "title": "\"Look at this\"",
        "textline": "\"It's another value for testing\"",
        "docuType": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listTitle": "\"Sample List\"",
    "listItems": [
      {
        "title": "\"Sample value\"",
        "textline": null,
        "docuType": "\"Analyse\""
      },
      {
        "title": "\"Sample value 2\"",
        "textline": null,
        "docuType": "\"IetsAnders\""
      },
      {
        "title": "\"SampleValue3!\"",
        "textline": null,
        "docuType": "\"Offerte\""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And finally, the code I use to make this happen;

```
Task <List<string>>listIDs = GetListIDs();
            listIDs.Wait();
            foreach (string id in listIDs.Result)
            {
                Task<string> lijstTitel = GetListTitle(id);
                lijstTitel.Wait();
                Task<List<string>> listitemIDs = GetItemIDs(id);
                listitemIDs.Wait();
                // Write all the items here
                foreach (string itemID in listitemIDs.Result)
                {

                    Task<ListItem> itempje = GetItem(itemID, id);
                    itempje.Wait();
                    listItems.Add(itempje.Result);
                }

                list.Add( new SPList{
                    listItems = listItems,
                    listTitle = lijstTitel.Result
                });
                listItems = new List<ListItem>();
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```

In the other example of the similar question I found, the person was serializing his JSON object twice, 'causing this problem to happen. Since I think I'm only serializing it once, does it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Tasks or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It looks like the strings actually contain quotes, can you check if that is the case?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You're right. This is quite embarrassing actually... I'm pretty new here, so should I actually remove this question now?

Comment: If you feel it has no future value to you or anyone else, then you can do that, assuming the site lets you. Just be aware that excessive deleting of questions might lead to some kind of reaction, but once or twice is not a problem. However, I've seen this question a few times and I think they've always been deleted so perhaps leave it?

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the backslashes `\`, it is the quotation marks `"`.
Looks like the data you are serializing is already quoted.

If you could remove the backslash you would still end up with double quotations marks in the output `""`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an "anwser"

Comment: Actually, it **is** the answer. The problem is not with the serialization, the problem is that the string values to serialize actually contains quotes, and those will be serialized with backslashes.

Comment: @Stefan: That is not possible. Look at my reputation.
I also disagree with you.